# Python regex non greedy not matching

Tags: python, regex

I have this text

```
This is test 2019 -(dsd) g1-d2 720p test
This test 2019 - g1-d2 test
```

They are separate lines so not together

I am trying to catch all stuff between 2019 and 720p if present

```
(.+?) ([0-9]{4})(.+?)([0-9]{3,4}p)?(.*)
```

The problem is group (.+?) is only matching single character. i want it to match till 720p . if use non greedy then it match everything

The output i want is

```
G1: This is test
G2: 2019
G3:  -(dsd) g1-d2 
G4: 720p
G5:  test
```

Comment: I think you want to catch all till 720p *or* end of the string. So instead of "unsure" ? use (([0-9]{3,4}p)(.*))|$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the `?` quantifier after `([0-9]{3,4}p)` as it will make the previous group optional and won't force the engine to match it.

**Edit**

To match strings with or without `720p`, you can enclose `(.+?)` and `([0-9]{3,4}p)` into an optional non-capturing group `(?:)?`.
Like so:

```
(.+?)([0-9]{4})(?:(.+?)([0-9]{3,4}p))?(.*)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/SYBMUv/3)

Comment: But that part may or may not be present so it wont be always there

Comment: Ok I thought you wanted to match the string only if 720p was present. See edit, should work as expected now.

Comment: Thanks man ur solution worked perfectly and was simple as well :) and close to mine

Answer (score 0):

Just need to play around with your lookbehinds and lookaheads.

```
(?<=2019)(.+?)(?=720p)
```

Gives me:

[image]

More info about lookahead and lookbehind assertions [here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

EDIT:

You can use regex patterns inside lookaheads if you need it to be more flexible. Here's one take:

```
(?<=[0-9]{4})(.+?)(?=[0-9]{3,4}p)
```

[image]

Comment: that 2019 and 720p is not fixed and can vary like any year and and resolution like 1080p 2160p

Comment: @rgd You can always substitute other regex patterns. See edit.

Comment: the group with 720p is optional so it wont always be there

Answer (score 0):

We can try doing a regex split on the following pattern:

```
 (?=\d{4})|(?<=\d{4}) | (?=\d{3,4}p)|(?<=\d{3}p) |(?<=\d{4}p)
```

Sample script:

```
input = "This is test 2019 -(dsd) g1-d2 720p test"
parts = re.split(r' (?=\d{4})|(?<=\d{4}) | (?=\d{3,4}p)|(?<=\d{3}p) |(?<=\d{4}p) ', input)
print(parts)
```

This prints:

```
['This is test', '2019', '-(dsd) g1-d2', '720p', 'test']
```

The idea here is to split using lookarounds which assert, but do not actually consume anything in the input.  We split whenever we lookahead or lookbehind and see a 4 digit year, or a 3-4 digit number followed by `p`.